# Silly Python Beginner

Tags: python, expression

Having some trouble grasping why this "quick math" formula I was taught in high school does not seem to work correctly.

The premise is to take your hourly salary, double it and add three Zeros, the result will roughly equate to your yearly salary if you work full time 50 weeks out of the year.

```
# Preface
print '---> Want to know your yearly salary? <---'.upper()

# Question
money = raw_input("How much money do you earn per hour?")

# Math Work
mult = money * 2
result = mult + str(000)

# Answer
print "you make roughly $%r per year, Working full-time for 50 weeks out of the year" % result
```

**Result:** 
my result looks something like this: "you make roughly $10100 per year, working full-time for 50 weeks out of the year"

I must be making a mistake in my expression...Simply put, I just do not know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got all the types wrong.

`raw_input` acquires a string, so `money` is acquired as such. Thus, when you do `mult=money*2` you are not doubling a *number*, but a string; writing `money*2` thus has the effect of creating a string that is the concatenation of two copies of the string you provided. If you enter `10`, `mult` will be `'1010'`.

Also, in `str(000)` `000` is an integer, so it's actually a plain `0`; `str(000)` thus results in `'0'`, which is concatenated to your doubled-string. `1010` concatenated with `'0'` => `10100`.

What you actually want is

```
# Question
money = int(raw_input("How much money do you earn per hour?"))

# Math Work
mult = money * 2
result = str(mult) + "000"
```

---

By the way, adding zeroes and the like is fine for humans, but since we are dealing with a computer you can just multiply by 2000:

```
result = 2000*int(raw_input("How much money do you earn per hour?"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to do math with a string. Convert it into an integer first:

```
money = int(raw_input("How much money do you earn per hour?"))
```

and multiply instead of trying to add a string to the end

```
result = money * 2000
```

Though if you really wanted to, you could convert the integer back to a string to add 3 zeros to the end:

```
mult = money * 2
strmult = str(mult)
result = strmult + '000'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `raw_input()` function returns a `string`.
When you multiply `money` by a number, instead of multiplying the integer value, you are multiplying the string value. This results in the variable's new value being a multiple of the string, or the string repeated multiple times. I would suggest using the `money=int(money)` function on money to turn it into an integer, or better yet `money=float(money)` to get a floating-point number.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
money=int(input('how much you make an hour'))
final_yearly=money*2000
print(final_yearly)
```

Answer (score -1):

You do realize the following would give you the desired answer, right?

```
#Math Work 
mult = money * 2000
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that `raw_input(...)` gets a string. Your code would result in a 2000-character string that starts with `'1010101010101010101010'`

Answer (score -1):

First, `money` is a string, when you read user input. So when the user inputs `10`, you get `'10'`.
So when you do `money*2`, you don't get the expected `20`. Rather, you get `'10'*2`, which is `'10'` concatenated twice, i/e/ `'1010'`.

Next, `000` is an `int` that evaluates to `0`, the `str` of which is `'0'`. What you wanted to add is `'000'`

I would go about your task this way:

```
# Preface
print '---> Want to know your yearly salary? <---'.upper()

# Question
money = int(raw_input("How much money do you earn per hour?"))

# Math Work
mult = money * 2
result = str(mult) + "000"
```

Alternatively, you could do this as well:

```
# Preface
print '---> Want to know your yearly salary? <---'.upper()

# Question
money = int(raw_input("How much money do you earn per hour?"))

# Math Work
result = money*2000  # because adding three 0s is the same as multiplying by 1000
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# Preface
print '---> Want to know your yearly salary? <---'.upper()

# Question
money = raw_input("How much money do you earn per hour?")

# Math Work

result = str(int(money)*2) + '000'
# Answer
print "you make roughly $%r per year, Working full-time for 50 weeks out of the year" % result
```